# how to add gift card to cart with custom function using ajax and php in woocomerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

i'm developing a theme for woocommerce and i use a custom add to cart function that works with ajax
also i added  [woocommeece gift card plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/gift-cards/)   but there is a problem, as gift cards are not a regular products we need to send some data to add cart. lest start with codes:
my code before gift card:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_add_to_cart_ajax');
function custom_add_to_cart_ajax()
{
    // Only run on single product pages
    if (!is_product()) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the product data
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $product_type = $product->get_type();
    $quantity_input = $product_type === 'variable' ? 'input.qty' : '.quantity';

?><script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('form.cart').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                var button = form.find('.single_add_to_cart_button');
                var quantity = form.find('<?php echo $quantity_input; ?>').val();
                var product_id = form.find('input[name="add-to-cart"]').val();
                var variation_id = form.find('input[name="variation_id"]').val();
                
                var data = {
                    action: 'custom_add_to_cart',
                    product_id: product_id,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    variation_id: variation_id,
                    security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("custom-add-to-cart-nonce"); ?>',
                    'woocommerce-cart-nonce': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("woocommerce-cart"); ?>'
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: PHPVARS.ajaxurl,
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {
                        ..... // removed unnesccery parts
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script><?php 
function custom_add_to_cart_ajax_callback()
            {
                check_ajax_referer('custom-add-to-cart-nonce', 'security');

                $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id',  absint($_POST['product_id']));
                $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
                $variation_id = isset($_POST['variation_id']) ? absint($_POST['variation_id']) : null;

                $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);

                if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id)) {
                    ob_start(); // start output buffering

                    wc_get_template_part('mini', 'cart');
                    $mini_cart_content = ob_get_clean();

                    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
                    wc_add_to_cart_message($product_id);
                    $notices = wc_get_notices();

                    wc_clear_notices();

                    // Send the AJAX response
                    wp_send_json_success(
                        array(
                            'cart_count' => $cart_count,
                            'mini_cart_content' => $mini_cart_content,
                            'notices' => $notices
                        )
                    );
                } else {

                    $notices = wc_get_notices();

                    wc_clear_notices();

                    $data = array(
                        'error' => true,
                        'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id),
                        'notices' => $notices
                    );

                    // Send the AJAX response
                    wp_send_json_error($data);
                }
                wp_die();
            }
```

it didnt work for gift cards: then i add this to my `custom_add_to_cart_ajax_callback()` :

```
if ($is_gift_card) {

                    $recipient_email = isset($_POST['recipient_email']) ? sanitize_email($_POST['recipient_email']) : '';
                    $gift_message = isset($_POST['gift_message']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['gift_message']) : '';
                    $gift_card_data = array(

                        'recipient' => $recipient_email,
                        'message' => $gift_message,
                    );

                    // Add the gift card item to the cart
                    $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, array(), $gift_card_data);
               

                    if ($cart_item_key) {
                        // Send the AJAX response
                        wp_send_json_success(
                            array(
                                'cart_count' => WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(),
                                'mini_cart_content' => wc_get_template_html(
                                    'cart/mini-cart.php',
                                    array(
                                        'cart' => WC()->cart,
                                    )
                                ),
                                'notices' => wc_get_notices(),
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        // Error adding the gift card to the cart
                        wp_send_json_error(
                            array(
                                'error' => true,
                                'message' => 'Error adding the gift card to the cart.',
                            )
                        );
                    }
                } else {
 regular product add to cart ...
```

it now work but it add gift card for the current user, for example if we want to sent gift card as
gift to someone and enter their email as reciption it dosnt handle that and fill it with current user email, **i want it to get the reciption email, from field , massage and delivary date as gift card data, how can i do that?**

notes:

- there is some form input that i can send their value with js in ajax : input names : recipient, sender, message (also this exact names in db)
- https://woocommerce.com/document/gift-cards/rest-api-reference/ REST API doc , but i dont know how should i use it in my function.

i tried to many thing as key names here

```
$gift_card_data = array(              
     'wc_gc_giftcard_to_multiple' => 'test@test.com',
     'wc_gc_giftcard_from' => 'test',
     'wc_gc_giftcard_message' => 'uuuuuuuu',
        );

// Add the gift card item to the cart
                    $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, array(), $gift_card_data);
```

also tried this to save meta data:

```
if ($cart_item_key && !empty($gift_card_data)) {
   foreach ($gift_card_data as $key => $value) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta($cart_item_key, $key, $value);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Having the same problem right now, did you figure out how to make this work?